# Show images from a function in a subplot

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I have a function (sample_show) which displays an image with its bounding box and this is working fine.

```
def sample_show(image_id=None):
    
    unique_imgs = df.image_id.unique()
    if image_id is None:
        idx = random.randrange(len(unique_imgs))
        img_id = unique_imgs[idx]
    img = cv2.imread(f'{TRAIN_DIR}{img_id}.jpg')
    
    img_df = df[df.image_id == img_id].copy()
    print('Total bounding boxes = {}'.format(img_df.shape[0]))

    
    for i in range(img_df.shape[0]):
        
        start_point = (img_df.iloc[i,:]['x'], img_df.iloc[i,:]['y'])
        end_point = (img_df.iloc[i,:]['x']+img_df.iloc[i,:]['w'], img_df.iloc[i,:]['y']+img_df.iloc[i,:]['h'])
        
        img = cv2.rectangle(img, start_point, end_point, 255, 2)

    plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
    sns.set_style('white')
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.title(f'{img_id}')
```

Now, I want to show these images on a subplot...

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(4, 1, figsize=(10, 40), sharex=True)
sns.despine(left=True)
    
for i in range(4):
    ...
```

Is there a way to show images using sample_show() on the subplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify your function so that it works on a particular Axes instance instead of creating a new figure every time.

```
def sample_show(image_id=None, ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()

    unique_imgs = df.image_id.unique()
    if image_id is None:
        idx = random.randrange(len(unique_imgs))
        img_id = unique_imgs[idx]
    img = cv2.imread(f'{TRAIN_DIR}{img_id}.jpg')
    
    img_df = df[df.image_id == img_id].copy()
    print('Total bounding boxes = {}'.format(img_df.shape[0]))

    
    for i in range(img_df.shape[0]):
        
        start_point = (img_df.iloc[i,:]['x'], img_df.iloc[i,:]['y'])
        end_point = (img_df.iloc[i,:]['x']+img_df.iloc[i,:]['w'], img_df.iloc[i,:]['y']+img_df.iloc[i,:]['h'])
        
        img = cv2.rectangle(img, start_point, end_point, 255, 2)

    ax.imshow(img)
    ax.set_title(f'{img_id}')
```